# Sequelize save in multiple tables

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Okay so i have a huge problem that i have no clue on how to fix. i have the following setup for my titles:

```
var Title = sequelize.define('title', {
        id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
        organization_id: DataTypes.INTEGER

    }, {
        freezeTableName: true,
        instanceMethods: {
            retrieveAll: function (onSuccess, onError) {
                Title.findAll({order: 'Rand'}, {raw: true})
                    .ok(onSuccess).error(onError);
            },
            retrieveById: function (quote_id, onSuccess, onError) {
                Title.find({where: {id: quote_id}}, {raw: true})
                    .success(onSuccess).error(onError);
            },
            add: function (selectedCompetence,onSuccess, onError) {

                var title = {id: null, name: this.dataValues.name, organization_id: this.dataValues.organization_id};
              Title.build(this.dataValues)
                    .save().ok(onSuccess).error(onError);
            },
            updateById: function (quote_id, onSuccess, onError) {
                var id = quote_id;
                var quotes = this.quotes;

                Title.update({quotes: quotes}, {where: {id: id}})
                    .success(onSuccess).error(onError);
            },
            removeById: function (quote_id, onSuccess, onError) {
                Title.destroy({where: {id: quote_id}}).success(onSuccess).error(onError);
            }
        }
    }
),
    Title_has_competence = sequelize.define('title_has_competence', {
        id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        title_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        competence_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        competence_level_id: DataTypes.STRING
    },{
        freezeTableName: true,
        instanceMethods: {
            retrieveAll: function (onSuccess, onError) {
                Title_has_competence.findAll({order: 'Rand'}, {raw: true})
                    .ok(onSuccess).error(onError);
            },
            retrieveById: function (quote_id, onSuccess, onError) {
                Title_has_competence.find({where: {id: quote_id}}, {raw: true})
                    .success(onSuccess).error(onError);
            },
            add: function (competence,onSuccess, onError) {
                var ins = {id: null, title_id:competence.title_id, competence_id: competence.id, competence_level_id: competence.level};
                Title_has_competence.build(ins)
                    .save().ok(onSuccess).error(onError);
            },
            updateById: function (quote_id, onSuccess, onError) {
                var id = quote_id;
                var quotes = this.quotes;

                Title_has_competence.update({quotes: quotes}, {where: {id: id}})
                    .success(onSuccess).error(onError);
            },
            removeById: function (quote_id, onSuccess, onError) {
                Title.destroy({where: {id: quote_id}}).success(onSuccess).error(onError);
            }
        }
    });
Title.belongsToMany(Title_has_competence,{foreignKey: 'competence_id'});
```

In my system when you create a title you pass along an array of competence:

In this case the competences is the array: `selectedCompetence` Once the title has been created i need to loop through the array of `selectedCompetence` and insert them into the `Title_has_competence` table.

I feel like i have litteraly tried everything from `Hooks` to minor hacks but nothing has worked.

Can anyone please push me in the right direction?

Things i have attempted:

```
  Title.build(this.dataValues)
    .save().done(function(err, success, selectedCompetence){
      var i = 0;  // here selectedCompetence is undefined
  });
```

---

```
  Title.build(this.dataValues)
    .save();
Title.hook('afterCreate', function(success,selectedCompetence){
    var i = 0; // here selectedCompetence is an object with other values
})
```

---

```
    Title.create({id: null, name: this.dataValues.name, organization_id:this.dataValues.organization_id}).then(function(title, selectedCompetence)
{
    var i = 0; // once again selectedCompetence is undefined
});
```

Comment: What version of Sequelize are you using? Some things changed a bit in the latest versions, for example `.belongsToMany()` now requires the `through` attribute...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the closest attempt was the `then()` approach. But the argument passed to the then-function after a `create()` is only the object that was just created, nothing else, so `then(function(title, someCompetence) ...` won't work.

You could try something like this:

```
// Let's say you already know the competence IDs
var competenceIds = [ 1, 2, 3 ]

// First, create the title
Title.create({ id: 1, name: 'Some Title' })
  .then(function(createdTitle) {
    // Build an array of promises. Each element waits for one competence
    // to be associated with the title.
    var associationPromises = [];
    competences.forEach(function(competenceId) {

      // associate one competence with the title
      associationPromises.push(Title_has_competence.create({
        title_id: createdTitle.id,
        competence_id: competenceId,
        competence_level_id: 123 // whatever else is on the join table
      })
    });

    // Wait for all the competences to be associated before continuing
    return Sequelize.Promise.all(associationPromises);
  });
```

This is a very low-level approach, which comes in handy when you have complex relations (like your join table that links multiple entities: Title, Competence, and Level).

But normally Sequelize can handle a lot of this automatically (see the [documentation on Relations](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/associations/)). For example, if you only had the Title-Competence relation, you could probably just write:

```
var Title = sequelize.define(...)
var Competence = sequelize.define(...)
Competence.belongsToMany(Title, {through: 'title_has_competence'});
Title.belongsToMany(Competence, {through: 'title_has_competence'});

Title.create({name: 'Some Title'}).then(function(createdTitle) {
  return createdTitle.setCompetences([1, 2, 3]);
});
```

(note: I actually think Sequelize *can* handle your case too, but I haven't used this feature yet; search for "additional attributes in your join table" in the documentation above)